# Designing a circuit to manage 3 power supplies

Tags: voltage, power, mosfet, circuit-design

I'm designing a low power wireless sensor node and trying to design a system to manage a potential of 3 power supplies. I have a main board (defined by that box), and an external board that can be connected (not in the box), but may not always be connected.

**I have three rules I want to follow:**

1. If VUSB is plugged in, VBAT & VSOLAR is disconnected
2. If VSOLAR is plugged in, VBAT is disconnected (VUSB unplugged)
3. If nothing other power sources, VBAT powers circuit

Currently the main board works. If PUSB is plugged in, the battery is disconnected and PUSB powers the circuit.

I am trying to design the external board so that it follows my 3 rules. Essentially when either PUSB are plugged in, or PSOLAR I want to charge the battery and power the circuit.

I am relying on the P-Channel MOSFETS to act as the switch, and the Schottky Diodes to prevent any reverse current flowing.

Will my circuit design work as intended? I did simulate it using Falstad, and it looked to work but I wanted to double check on here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgL8X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It is a logical task. Create truth table.

Comment: The logic isn't a concern of mine, I comprehend that. My concern is that the circuit doesn't do what my truth table (following my rules) would represent.